# How to use for loop array to add series dynamically for line chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, highcharts, series

I have to Pass array to `series` which generating from ajax code.
I have this multiple fields/array Linehart values `Result[i].MONTHLY_TOTAL_FTE`, MonthYear `Result[i].MONTH + Result[i].YEAR`, Country `Result[i].COUNTRY_NAME` 
So I have to show a line chart according to this.

I am using below snippet code

```
$.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/api/ReportAPI/GetMonthlyEmployeeFte",
                data: '{}',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (Result) {
                  var data = [];
                  var data2 = [];
                  var data3 = [];
                  for (var i in Result) {                     
                    var serie = new Array(Result[i].MONTH + Result[i].YEAR);
                    data.push(serie);
                    var fte = new Array(Result[i].MONTHLY_TOTAL_FTE);                       
                    data2.push(fte);
                    var contry = new Array(Result[i].COUNTRY_NAME);                      
                    data3.push(contry); 
                    }                    
                    DreawLineChart(data, data2, data3);                                                   
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                }
            }); 


     function DreawLineChart(series, ssssss,contryname) {
     Highcharts.chart('container2', {
        chart: {
            type: 'line'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Monthly Employee FTE'        },
        subtitle: {
            //text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
        },
        xAxis: {
            //categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
            categories: series
        },     
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'FTE'
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            line: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                },
                enableMouseTracking: false
            }
        },
        /* series: [{
             name: 'Singapore',
             data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.4, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]

         }, {
             name: 'New Zealand',
             data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]
         }] */
           series: [{
               name:contryname, //'Singapore',
          data: JSON.parse("[" + ssssss + "]") //[3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5] //ftes
          }]

    });
   }
```

problem is that it's showing data for Japan country but its showing data of other countries in Japan.on clik on Other countries like new Zealand, Singapore its showing blank.

[image: chart]

My sql store procedure to fetch data

```
SELECT YEAR(POSBDGT.[PLAN_START_DATE]) as [POSITION_FTE_YEAR],
  MONTH(POSBDGT.[PLAN_START_DATE]) as [POSITION_FTE_MONTH_NO],
  CONVERT(varchar(3),DATENAME(month,POSBDGT.[PLAN_START_DATE])) as [POSITION_FTE_MONTH],
  SUM([TOTALFTE]) AS [TOTALFTE], 
  COMAST.[name]
  FROM [DBO].[POSITION_FTE] POSFTE WITH (NOLOCK)
  INNER JOIN [DBO].[POSITION_BUDGET] POSBDGT WITH (NOLOCK) ON POSFTE.POSITION_ID = POSBDGT.POSITION_ID
   INNER JOIN [DBO].POSITION_LOCATION POSLOC WITH (NOLOCK) ON POSLOC.POSITION_ID = POSFTE.POSITION_ID
  INNER JOIN [DBO].[country_master] COMAST WITH (NOLOCK) ON COMAST.[country_id] = POSLOC.COUNTRY_ID
  GROUP BY COMAST.[name], YEAR(POSBDGT.[PLAN_START_DATE]),DATENAME(month,POSBDGT.[PLAN_START_DATE]),MONTH(POSBDGT.[PLAN_START_DATE])
```

Table Results

[image: table]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are facing is that the layout of your `series` is looking like the following:

```
series: [{
          name: ['England', 'Japan', 'Singapore']  //contryname
          data: JSON.parse("[" + [1, 2, 3, 4]+ "]") //ssssss
```

In order for Highcharts to work you need the following format

```
    series: [{
                 name: 'Singapore',
                 data: [7.0, 6.9]

             }, {
                 name: 'New Zealand',
                 data: [3.9, 4.2]
             }]
```

You can achieve this by making sure your Result loop looks like this:

```
 $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/api/ReportAPI/GetMonthlyEmployeeFte",
                data: '{}',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (Result) {
                      var data = []
                      var categories = []
                      for (var i in Result) {                     
                          var serie = new Array(Result[i].MONTH + Result[i].YEAR);
                          categories.push(serie);
                          var fte = {name: Result[i].COUNTRY_NAME, data: 
                                     [Result[i].MONTHLY_TOTAL_FTE]};                       
                          data.push(fte);      
                          }  
                  DreawLineChart(categories, data);                                                   
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                }
            }); 





    function DreawLineChart(categories, dataArray) {
         Highcharts.chart('container2', {
            chart: {
                type: 'line'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Monthly Employee FTE'        },
            subtitle: {
                //text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: categories
            },     
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'FTE'
                }
            },
            plotOptions: {
                line: {
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true
                    },
                    enableMouseTracking: false
                }
            },
             series: dataArray //This is where the new array of data appears

        });
       }
```

The above code takes the result and converts it to the format I mentioned above. This should be solving your problem. However, I wasn't fully able to reproduce your input as it wasn't given.

Comment: its showing only country names refer this link image https://ibb.co/ebnJN7

Comment: My apologies, I forgot some syntax. I updated my answer and now it should show the data points in different series.

Comment: still not showing logs:- (5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0
:
data
:
["6"]
name
:
"Japan"
_colorIndex
:
0
_symbolIndex
:
0
__proto__
:
Object
1
:
data
:
["2"]
name
:
"New Zealand"
_colorIndex
:
1
_symbolIndex
:
1
__proto__
:
Object

Comment: @SanjayNakate   The `data : ["6"]` part makes me think the results have been parsed as a string instead of integer. Is it stored within the Result object as String or integer?

Comment: check this image https://ibb.co/mnHM9n , after parse its showing data like this but it's showing wrong var fte = {
                            name: Result[i].COUNTRY_NAME,
                            data: JSON.parse("[" + Result[i].MONTHLY_TOTAL_FTE + "]") //[Result[i].MONTHLY_TOTAL_FTE]
                        };

Comment: It is not showing wrong, as the code doesn't take into account there are differences in dates/months. You will need to make sure the series contain values on every point you want to plot. If you want to plot 3 months, your arrays need to have a length of 3, with a 'null' value if the value does not belong to said month. However, that was not your question. You asked how to dynamically add series to your highchart. If this were 5 points plotted for March, it shows what it needs to show.